# Django ignoring routers settings

Tags: django

I'm trying to setup a router in Django but it's not working it just seems to be ignored all together, I have added the DATABASE_ROUTERS on settings and created the db router as well:

**settings.py**

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['misc.routers.MasterSlaveRouter',]
```

**routers.py**

```
class MasterSlaveRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        print "Router"
        return 'dbname'
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return None
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return None
    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        return None
```

but it just seems to not be used at all

outline

```
misc/
- __init__.py
- settings.py
- routers.py
- urls.py

otherapp/
- __init__.py
- views.py
....
```

misc is the main project name

Comment: Please post your code here rather than linking to pasebin.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in `routers` directory?

Comment: @Selcuk routers is just the name of the file, it's not it's own folder, routers.py is in the same folder as settings.py

Comment: What is misc then? Can you post your project directory outline?

Comment: @Selcuk I added the outline now, misc is the main project name

Comment: Is there ``__init__.py`` file in your misc directory?

Comment: In your outline the filename is `router.py` while you are referring to it as `misc.routers...` is it a typo?

Comment: @Selcuk yes it was a typo, the name is consistent, but it doesn't really matter, whatever I put in on the DATABASE_ROUTERS settings it will just readily ignore it

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as @ShinySides ... Either something in router configurations is broken, or incredibly unclear. I've had them work in previous version of Django, but no luck on 1.8

Comment: I was able to make it work by adding a new routers/ module and defining the Router in the ```__init__.py```

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar and got round it by adding an if statement in with the else returning None:

```
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints) :
    if model._meta.app_label == 'your_app_name' :
        return 'dbname'
    else :
        return None
```

No idea why it needed this but it resolved the issue for me. May be worth a try.